# Random number generator wont work with parseInt?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this function that does a random number between 100 and 1 in JS and it adds it to the Score keeper, but the score keeper wont work. I even added `parseInt` for it to convert it from a string to an actually numbers `int` but it gives me `NaN`. But when I remove `parseInt` it gives me stacked numbers.  Example: `50 + 100` will become `50100` not `150`. Is there something wrong with the code? Here is the HTML and JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pets.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Score Keeper</h1>
        <button onclick="randGen()">Random Numbers</button>
        <p id="paragraph"></p>
    </div>
    <h2 id="score"></h2>
    <script src="pets.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
const scoreKeeper = document.getElementById('score');
scoreKeeper = 0;

function randGen() {
    const p = document.getElementById('paragraph');
    const generatedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let currentNumber = parseInt(scoreKeeper.innerText) ?? 0

    if (generatedNumber > 0) {
        p.innerHTML = `Your number is: ${generatedNumber}`
        currentNumber += generatedNumber;
        scoreKeeper.innerText = currentNumber;
        return scoreKeeper;
    }
}
```

Comment: `parseInt("")` is `NaN`, and `NaN ?? 0` is `NaN` since `NaN` isn't nullish. Use `||` instead since `NaN` is falsy.

Comment: @FZs `scoreKeeper` is `const`, hence `scoreKeeper = 0` will just throw an `Invalid assignment` type error

Comment: Check your console before posting! your code can't validate, you got this **error :{
  "message": "TypeError: invalid assignment to const 'scoreKeeper'",**

Comment: I am voting to close this question because this code contains a simple error. The PO did not do this simple check in his console before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a simple javaScript mistake. You are overwriting `const`. The aspect of `const` is that the value can NOT be overwritten. change it to `let`.

Also, you get an element `document.getElementById("score")` but then automatically overwrite it as 0. Also also, doing `parseInt(scoreKeeper.innerText) ?? 0` checks if you can `parseInt` the `innerText` rather then if the `innerText` exist. You should check if it exist first and then `parseInt` it.

```
let scoreKeeper = document.getElementById("score");

function randGen() {
  let p = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  const generatedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  let currentNumber = scoreKeeper.innerText
    ? parseInt(scoreKeeper.innerText)
    : 0;

  if (generatedNumber > 0) {
    p.innerHTML = `Your number is: ${generatedNumber}`;
    currentNumber += generatedNumber;
    scoreKeeper.innerText = currentNumber;
  }
}
```

Also, the return in this case in not needed. You do not return a value to any other function or place. You are modifying your `h2` and `p` inner text directly from the function.

EDIT

You can make the code more readable and using less global variables by making an if check to check if the value is what you do not want and just do an empty `return`, and move the `let scoreKeeper` inside the function. Declare all other variables, besides the `generatedNumber`, after the check and return to only create variables and use up memory if the conditions are met.

```
function randGen() {
  const generatedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  if (generatedNumber <= 0) return;
  let scoreKeeper = document.getElementById("score");
  let p = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  let currentNumber = scoreKeeper.innerText
    ? parseInt(scoreKeeper.innerText)
    : 0;
  p.innerHTML = `Your number is: ${generatedNumber}`;
  currentNumber += generatedNumber;
  scoreKeeper.innerText = currentNumber;
}
```